# Docker compose up --build W: failed to fetch

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I am trying to run `docker compose up --build` but I am receiving those messages:

```
+ apt-get update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (199.232.114.132), connection timed out Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (199.232.114.132), connection timed out Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.114.132 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Docker Compose V2 to import/build images from a container. Does someone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: There could me a million different issues here. Can you access that url from your command line (non-container?). Can you spin up a container and get to google? It could be a DNS issue with your docker setup, it could be DNS on your host machine. It could be an air-gapped machine with no access to the internet, there's not a lot to go off of here.

Comment: I do not think this is docker's fault. Most likely it is a problem with the debian version you are using as a base image that might be a little old and maybe the package repos have been moved.